# Ruby on rails, how to start new line in string to send in email body content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I try to send an email using the content generated in the ruby on rails code as followings.
I want to show in email the following things,
Hello
World

I tried to use the code like follows,

```
content = "Hello\n"
content += "World\n"
GeneralMailer.monitor_report("Test",content).deliver
```

GeneralMailer and moniter_report are well set up. 
What I got from email is still "HelloWorld"

Are there any ways to separate these to different lines?
Thank you

Comment: I would highly recommend you use ERB views for your mailer needs. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not pass the string as an array

```
content = Array.new
content << "Hello"
content << "World"
```

when you pass an object, you still use it as html format like this

```
<div>
  <%=content[0]%>
  <br>
  <%=content[1]%>
</div>
```

or
for more references/tutorials on action mailer: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Comment: How can I fit your print part as one variable part? Thanks~

Comment: Can I ask why you need it as one variable?

Comment: So can I use the html format or other stuff to send back the email body? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer. You can use it as .html.erb in the view of the mailer

Comment: If the option of using HTML format is available for you try this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: That works. In addition, how to handle array with unknown number of element in it. Thanks.

Comment: in ruby, arrays are dynamically resizable. you can append elements to them and they grow as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **\n** try

**\r\n**

```
    content = "Hello\r\n"
content += "World\r\n"
GeneralMailer.monitor_report("Test",content).deliver
```

Comment: Can you tell me what enviornment/ os and what version of rails?

Comment: Rails 3.2.16 and OSX. I am curious what kind of structure to use to send back the email body. Thank you.